# Targeting button to form from other form

Tags: html, forms

This one is possible to make with JavaScript, but I'm curious about pure HTML solution. What's my point of this question:

I have a form:

```
<form action...>
    <input type... />
    <label for...>...</label>
    and other elements for basic form...

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
    <button type="submit" target="hidden-form">Remove</button>
</form>
```

And somewhere else I have this another form:

```
<form id="hidden-form" action...>
    <input type="hidden"... />
</form>
```

So my point is, that pressing button "Remove" will post form `#hidden-form`. Is something like that possible? I tried that attribute `target`, but no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`<button>`'s form attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp):

```
<button type="submit" form="hidden-form">Remove</button>

<form id="hidden-form" action...>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like that. I already found a solution, I compeltely rebuilded it, but this one seems to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, using jQuery it is possible try it:

```js
$("#remove").click(function(){
 $('#hidden-form').submit();
});
```

```html
<form action...>
    <input type... />
    <label for...>...</label>
    and other elements for basic form...

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
    <button type="submit" id="remove" onClick="document.forms['hidden-form'].submit();
">Remove</button>
</form>


<form id="hidden-form" action...>
    <input type="hidden"... />
</form>
```

Comment: I know it is possible with JS, but I'm looking for pure HTML solution, that would be the best.